# Find bases for orthogonal complement $S^\perp$ for the subspace $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, span

I'm having a tough time understanding the textbook on how to answer this question? I'm not too sure what to do? Any help will be appreciated.

$$
S=\operatorname{span}\left[ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -3 
\end{pmatrix} \right]
$$

Could I use any vector that is orthogonal to the span $S$ as the basis?

Comment: Yes; that will be enough in this case. That is, the orthogonal complement has dimension $2-1=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach is correct here.  In particular, we can say
$$
S^\perp = \text{span}\left\{ \pmatrix{3\\1} \right\}
$$